# Proper statistical test selection / SPSS setup

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

---

UPDATE: Basically, my question boils down to, how can I compare the distribution of yes's and no's BETWEEN multiple subgroups to see if their difference is statistically significant (and get a p value)?

You can ignore the rest below.

---

I'm curious if i've set up my variables correctly in SPSS and if I've run the proper tests.  If not, I'd appreciate any help I can get!  As an overview, I'm trying to see if a policy has helped increase the rate of mammogram screenings.

I have data I'd like compared across two independent variables:

--Year (2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015) - I've set as Nominal (not sure if this should be scale)
--Clinic (A, B, C)

My dependent variable is whether the qualifying patients in each clinic's EMR followed through with getting a mammogram for each year.  So I have a total of 26,202 Yes's and No's (or 1s and 0s) that fall into the above categories.

I'd like to see if the differences in the frequency of yes's and no's is significant based on year and further subdivided by clinic.

Which test should I run and how should I set up my data?

I've already run ANOVA, but each case may not be independent (i.e. same patient may be repeated each year) and my data is not normally distributed as I'm basically looking at the frequency of a dichotomous variable.  Does that apply if a dichotomous variable is converted to a frequency (percentage?)

Here's a table summary of my data if that helps:

[image]

Any help would be greatly, greatly, sorely appreciated.

Comment: Why are you running ANOVA on count data? Unless the null is true, the assumption of equal variance cannot be true for a start.

Comment: Yes, I'm realizing i made the incorrect choice, which is why I've posted here.  Any suggestions for a proper alternative?

Comment: Do you know which patients are the same when it's the "same patient"?

Comment: Unfortunately, not with the data I've been given.

Comment: Basically, my question boils down to, how can I compare the distribution of yes's and no's BETWEEN multiple subgroups to see if their difference is statistically significant?